# ffmpg: generate very small size video out of pictures

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Using JPEG pictures, I'd like to generate a video with the smallest possible size. In the ffmpeg doc, it says one can use a 1 fps frame rate. Is it possible to go below that to have a even smaller video file size (like 1 new picture displayed every 2-3secs?)

Answer (score 2):

The following should produce a video with 0.5 fps (one frame every other second):

```
ffmpeg -r 0.5 -i Input%d.jpg Output.mp4
```